# Any book discussing Tournament Topics in Graph Theory.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Anyone know what book is the best discussing the Tournament topics in graph? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are 'tournament topics'? Do you mean to say graph theory topics which frequently appear in tournaments/contests?

Comment: @shardulc. Graph Theory books which contain or discuss tournaments..

Comment: A tournament is the directed analogue of a complete graph, i.e. you just give directions to all edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[J. W. Moon's 1968 text "Topics on Tournaments"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/42833) is a classical text on the subject.